# Paypal mobile sdk integration with Ionic app

Tags: ionic-framework, paypal

All

We are having some trouble when we have had integrated paypal plugin in our ionic app,When we tried to make a transaction , following are the Alerts we got stopping the payment:

1. While using Paypal account.
   "**There was a problem setting up this payment. Please visit the PayPal website to check your account**."
2. While using Credit Card:
   **"The merchant does not accept payments of this type."**

Any help must be appreciated.

Thanks In Advance..

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue and been searching for few days. Then i tried making a new sandbox account and a corresponding new REST API APP and used the new app's Client ID. everything worked well !!

Comment: What about the Secret Key shouldn't be integrated as well into the plugin as the Client ID?